# How to insert data in SQLAlchemy tables with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I know that this issue was there. But I ask you to help me with this example.
I have this model:

```
ItemTable = Table('ItemTable', Base.metadata,
    Column('post_id', Integer, ForeignKey('post.id')),
    Column('tags_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id')))

class Post(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = Column(Text)
    body = Column(Text)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=ItemTable, backref='post')

    def __init__(self,title=None,body=None):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.title)

class Tag (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column (Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = Column (Text)
    posts = relationship ('Post', secondary=ItemTable, backref='tag')

    def __init__(self,title=None):
        self.title = title

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag %r>' % (self.title)
```

I tried to add a post with few tags. How can I do it rightly?
If I do it like this, I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

```
class AddPost(BaseView):
def is_accessible(self):
    return g.user.is_authenticated()
@expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def addpost_view(self):
    if not g.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('AdminView.login_view'))
    form = PostForm()
    if helpers.validate_form_on_submit(form):
        p=Post(title=form.title.data, body=form.text.data)
        for tag in form.tags.data.split(','):
            p.tags.append(tag)
        db_session.add(p)
        db_session.commit()
    self._template_args['form'] = form
    return self.render('admin/addpost.html')
```

Answer (score 4):

You are appending strings to the `Post` object instead of `Tag` objects.
The problem is here:

```
for tag in form.tags.data.split(','):
    p.tags.append(tag)
```

And it should look somehow like this:

```
for t in form.tags.data.split(','):
    tag = Tag(....)
    p.tags.append(tag)
```